# Why do certain disk operations hang for like ~7 seconds before they are executed?

Tags: windows-10, performance

Starting a couple of days ago, I am experiencing very strange performance issues with my Windows 10 PC. Certain file operations like starting programs will hang for about ~7 seconds before they are executed.

**My PC**

- AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
- 48GB DDR4 memory
- 2x 512GB SSD
- NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER
- Windows 10 Pro 20H2 19042.844

**Examples**

- Taking a screenshot with WIN+SHIFT+S will take for like 7 seconds before the tooltip shows up. Clicking it will immediately show Snip & Sketch but will take another 7 seconds to show the screenshot.
- Clicking the Slack icon in my taskbar will do nothing for 7 seconds, then the app shows immediately.
- Using "Save link as..." in Chrome will take about 7-9 seconds to show the file chooser.
- Opening Gimp will take ~7 seconds before the splash screen shows and another ~7 seconds when it
  tries to load *.exe plugins.
- Opening task manager will show an empty white window for about 8 seconds, then load the contents.

Negative examples:

- Opening the calculator will happen immediately.
- Copying a 2,5G file from disk A to disk B takes like 3 seconds.

**Other observations**

- Disk usage is very low all the time
- Looking at resource monitor it seems that there is no disk usage at all for the 7 second hang period.
- There are also no other processes with spiking CPU/memory/disk usage in this period.
- Running a command like "echo test" on PowerShell is executed immediately.

**I have already tried the following without success:**

- Uninstalled all file system related sync clients like Google Drive, Onedrive etc.
- Uninstalled recently installed software.
- Installed the latest updates for Windows and drivers.
- Disabled Window's real-time protection.
- Started Windows in safe mode.
- Disconnected peripherals.

Comment: It's possible that the drives are failing, or since they are SSDs, they may just need TRIMed.

Comment: It could be Defender scanning the app before it is allowed to be launched.

Comment: Perhaps check `Event Viewer` [ find in Cortana] Windows Logs to see if there are any issues - a long list of messages may take a long time to display so it may be easier to `Clear Log ...` / save before clear before re-trying the action.

Comment: I've tried TRIMing, disabling all realtime scanning and checked the event viewer. There is nothing suspicious. Using process explorer I was able to see that there is really no activity going on during the hang period.

I figured out that using "save image as" will cause the process to hang on Chrome, but not on Firefox despite showing the same file chooser dialog. Only difference is that Firefox is not a sub process of explorer.exe.

Comment: OK wrong info about the browsers. Firefox will go to "Not responding" for a couple of seconds when using "save image as" for the first time but will work fine after that. In Chrome the dialog will just take 5+ seconds to load every time.